# Is there a possibility to write or print \ into a console

Tags: c#, ascii

I have a question. Can I write \ into a conosle in vscode? I tried to print an ascii character into the console for my little project that I am working on, because I am trying to learn c#
I have tired everything and the only thing I get is this message: the constant contains the newline character.
I know what it means because \n make a new line. I tried to search the internet and I didnt see anything related to what I am asking. Any help?
Thank you for seeing this question
-Henry

Comment: Console.Write() doesn't work?

Comment: Do you mean `Console.Write("\\");`?

Comment: You're asking about C# Escape Sequences. Here's a list of escape sequences, including the one you're looking for (`\\`).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I dont know why it didnt work but for some reason I had to restart vscode. I had a bug that prevented me from writing \.

Comment: The two most usual ways are `"string\\with\\backslash"` and `@"string\with\backslash"` which both produce the same value with length 19. There are other ways, including `"string\u005Cwith\u005Cbackslash"` and `$"string{(char)0x5C}with{(char)0x5C}backslash"`.

Comment: If it is for file paths, consider stuff like `Path.Combine("string", "with", "backslash")` which will contain a suitable separator (on a system where `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` is the backslash char).

Answer (score 1):

The backslash (`\`) is used as an escape character in C#. You can find the documentation  about escape sequences [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=msvc-170)

When you type just one backslash, the compiler will therefore interpret this character (and the next one) as an escape sequence.

Like Progman suggested, you can type "`\\`" to display a backslash in the Console.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can print `\` on console.
`\` is actually an escape sequence, hence the confusion.
Check this for escape sequences : [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/escape-sequences-c/)

To print "\" on the console in C# -

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Print \\");
```